# Having intercommunicating asynchronous processes in wxPython

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, wxpython, parallels

I am working on a big project that puts performance as a high priority. I have a little bit of experience using wxPython to create windows and dialog boxes for software, but I have no experience in getting processes to work in parallel during the course of a single program.

So basically, what I want to accomplish is the following:

I want one main class that controls the high level program. It sets up a configuration either from a config file or from user input. This much I have accomplished on my own.

I need PROCESS #1 to read in a file and a list of commands, execute the commands, and then pass the modified file to PROCESS #2 (this requires that PROCESS #2 is ready to accept new input.) Once the file is passed, PROCESS #1 would begin work on the next set of inputs and wait for PROCESS #2 to finish before the cycle repeats.

PROCESS #2 takes input from PROCESS #1 and writes output to a log file. Once the output is complete, it waits for the next set of output from PROCESS #1.

I know how to use wxTimers and the events associated with that, but what I have found is that a timer event will not execute if the program is otherwise occupied (like in the middle of a method.)

I have seen threads about "threading" and "Pool", but the terminology tends to go over my head, and I haven't gotten any of that sort of stuff to work.

If anybody can point me in the right direction, I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

Comment: Okay, so let me see if I can interpret this correctly. From the first example in the link, the guy created his own Event objects. This certainly seems like a more viable solution than when I was trying to use threading.Thread. I will try creating Events in the same sort of way and use those to trigger when PROCESS #1 and PROCESS #2 start and stop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use threads, then I think this would be fairly easy to do. Here's what I would suggest:

Create a button (or some other widget) to execute process #1 in a thread. The thread itself will run BOTH processes. Here's some psuedo-code that might help:

```
# this is in your thread code:
result = self.call_process_1(args)
self.call_process_2(result)
```

This will allow you to start another process #1/2 with a new set of commands every time you press the button. Since the two processes are encapsulated in the thread, they don't have to wait for process #2 to finish. You will probably need to log to separate logs for the logs to make sense, but you can label the logs with a timestamp and a thread number or a uuid.

Depending on how many of these processes you need to do, you might need to look into setting up a cluster that's driven with celery or some such. But I think this is a good starting place.